# Working with Entity Manager from other bundle

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have an application which serves a central hub for multiple other applications.

So my Vendor folder contains bundles, that are actually the main bundles for other applications.

Now from my central application I want to load a page from one of these main bundles.

The problem is that the default entity manager is used in these main bundles. Now that they are loaded in my central app, it should use the non-default manager (which has been properly configured in config.yml)

How do I tell these main bundles to now use the corresponding entity manager?

Comment: You can reuse the connection-name when injecting the entity manager. E.g. `@doctrine.orm.%connection_name_here%_entity_manager`. Is that what you need?

Comment: I want to keep the bundle in the vendor directory untouched. i am just calling the controller from the central application, so there is no injection happening here.

Comment: Ok, I can't really see how you wired this up, but if it is multiple entity managers, then you'll need to specify which entity manager to use (by connection name) whenever you inject the service or access a manager inside a controllre (e.g. `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager('%connection_name%')`). Or maybe the `default_connection` configuration option helps?

Comment: one quick solution I just found is to rename all the default connection names in the config.yml from the other main applications and rename the getManager() to ->getManager('app_connection_name')) in these projects as well. Make sure the 'app_connection_name'-connection exists under the doctrine configuration in the central application